# Why do I obtain the message error "no numeric types to aggregate?"

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, numeric

Good morning, I checked other questions but I can't figure out why I have the error "No numeric types to aggregate"? The objective of my code is to find the price value of CAC 40 in a time series.

My source of code: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1vqqJCpYSrhxp9VT8Tnvpts44AwB6GYK7#scrollTo=BE-71GALHCQb

I want to obtain this for CAC 40.

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df2 = pd.read_csv("/CAC 40 Historical Data.csv")
print(df2.head)

df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'])
print(df2.head())

df2.columns
df2.loc[:,'Price']

%matplotlib inline


sns.set()
plt.title('CAC 40 Prices')
sns.lineplot(df2['Date'], df2['Price'])
```

Can you help me? Thank you.

Comment: Please provide some info about the file you're using, what the data looks like and exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Ok. I'm new user. I try to understand how to ask very well a question. And to add my file

Comment: @ArielA, I try to add an image to show what i want. How to do it? This is very comple this website!!!

Comment: When you edit your question, there is an image button on the middle part of the top.

Comment: Excellent. I've found image. I try to  create hosting service to share my original data.

Comment: Thank you! 1] I added a link for image, but not the image. How you did it?           
 2] Which tool do you use to add file?

Comment: What about the actual csv file and the full error stack (the error message)? If I were to guess, your dataframe seems to not have a float attribute for the values you're using. Maybe `df2(dtype=float)` might work for you.

Comment: ok @ArielA thank you very much. I will try. Do you have access to my google colab file?

Comment: I can't manage the problem with df2(dtype=float) :/

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to do. Try looking through this tutorial if you're trying to create a plot out of a dataframe: https://queirozf.com/entries/pandas-dataframe-plot-examples-with-matplotlib-pyplot

Comment: Thank you.@ArielA. It seems an interesting source. I will send you the code if i solve my problem.

Comment: My error was only at the beginning: in the csv file, some datas were object instead of float 64. So, i created only general datz in my csv file except dates. https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1vqqJCpYSrhxp9VT8Tnvpts44AwB6GYK7?usp=sharing